# FragmentStatePagerAdapter getCount() is not called

Tags: android, notifydatasetchanged, fragmentstatepageradapter

I am using FragmentStatePagerAdapter in my app.
My problem is that when I am doing notifyDataSetChanged() it's calling only the getCount() and not the getItem().  the getCount is not returning 0. 
this is my FragmentStatePagerAdapter:

```
private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return titles.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragmentList.size();
    }
}
```

How could it be that after `pagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` only the getCount() is called and the `getItem(int position)` is not being called after it?
Thanks!

Comment: Are there any real changes in the fragment list? If not, `getItem()` should not be called. getCount() is called just routine call of the first checks if the size is changed.

Comment: How can the getItem() know if there is a change or not?! In any case, the size of the fragmentList is changing...

Comment: Once there are changes and those changes need to be populated , get item is called. Thats what i meant.

Comment: Ok, but as I said, fragmentList is changing

Comment: Are you replacing old ones or adding new items?

Comment: I am trying trying to...

Answer (score 0):

From [Issue 19001](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19001), I found that `int getItemPosition(Object object)` needs to be implemented in the `FragmentStatePageAdapter` subclass.  By default this method is assumed to return `POSITION_UNCHANGED` which will not trigger getItem to be called.  However, I, also, ran into issues (possible bugs in the android support library) when I implemented anything other than `return POSITION_NONE`.

Snippet from my adapter:

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return DiceRollerFragment.instantiate(position);
}
```